# Right phrase to request for introduction

Tags: phrases, british-english

I have been hearing some podcasts, in every podcast I hear, the anchor asks the guests

> Why don't you introduce yourself?

And, in some other I heard this phrase

> Can you kindly introduce about yourself?

It seems that second one seems to be convincing. Can we use the first one, in professional communication?

Comment: That second one does *not* "seem to be convincing". You can either *introduce yourself* or *say something about yourself*, but you can't ***introduce about** anything* in English. You should be able to establish that from any dictionary. Please consider posting on 
[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) in future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you find the second one more convincing. One cannot 'introduce about' someone. One can *has to introduce oneself*. You can ask, "Can you kindly tell us about yourself?"

I personally prefer the first one in a professional setting, provided it's asked in a warm intonation.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce is a transitive verb and as such introduce about yourself is grammatically unacceptable.You can further look it up in a learners dictionary regarding the usage of transitive and intransitive verbs.